# How to make an excel non-editable?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I export excel in protected or using password manner and there is a chance to unprotect the sheet. I want that, there is no option to edit after export the excel in vb.net.

Answer (score 1):

To make a column non-editable:

1. Select the whole worksheet, Right Click->Format Cells->Protection, uncheck the "Locked" check box.
2. Select the column you want to protect, right Click->Format Cells->Protection, select the "Locked" check box.
3. Review tab->Protect Sheet, select the "Protect worksheet and contents of locked cells" check box and protect the sheet using a password.

Comment: Using password chances has unprotect the worksheet. Without using password i want to make the sheet non-editable and moreover after export from vb.net the exported file wont be edit at any cost